# fft (fast Fourier transform) to speed up opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, fft

i have a raspberry pi with opencv and python installed. I want is to do a simple frontal face haarcascade using opencv. It works however i only have about 2 fps. So i searched through the internet and found this: `https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/accelerating-fourier-transforms-using-the-gpu/`

I think it's quiet interesting, but how do i implement it into python?

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you manage to compile the C source?

Answer (score 0):

You can highly improve the performance of the classification when you specify the parameters correctly.
Just set the min,max frame size to reasonable values and maybe set a scale factor.

For the fft there are already some python packages available for that.
I would not recommend to write your own fft function, since the library functions a mostly optimized and you will unlikely be able to write a faster version yourself.
There is another issue posted for that topic:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5348

They linked a github repo for this as well:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/apps/hello_pi/hello_fft